# How can I get my Netbook upgrade to 11.10 to use the new system button?

Tags: 11.10, unity

Most, if not all, the user interface updated correctly when I went from Natty to Oneiric but the system button did not. How can I get rid of the ugly purple monitor icon to be replaced with the new icon used by Oneiric? Is it a Unity-2D thing?

[image: Desktop Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general your icon theme looks outdated. Open the system settings and change the theme to high contrast, then back to Ambiance.

If that doesn't fix it, then run:

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mono humanity-icon-theme`.

If the theme does not automatically update, change the theme as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Roland, switching to High Contrast then back to Ambiance worked.